# How do I reset Curl variables in PHP?

Tags: php, curl

I want to do a number of Curl calls in a row, the first one is a post, but for the second one I just want to load a page and not post anything to do.

Here is my code, which does not work

```
$url = 'http://www.xxxx.com/results.php';
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt ($curl_handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, $tor);
curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_SOCKS5);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);

curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"); 
$data = 'Manufacturer=1265';
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS ,$data);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);

$dest = 'http://www.xxxx.com/search.php';
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_GET, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $dest);
$result = curl_exec ($curl_handle);
curl_close ($curl_handle); 
echo $result;
```

When I close the curl handle and open a new one for the second request it works fine. I do not think this is best practice though?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can issue multiple different types of calls easily, just keep calling setopt to switch between GET and POST, and change the URL as needed:

```
... your code up to the exec()...

curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://....';
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);

curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://....';
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(...));
$buffer = curl_exec($curl_handle);
```

Just change the OPTs you need to. Curl will ignore previously set ones that don't apply to the current request (e.g. don't bother clearing POSTFIELDS while doing a get, because they won't get used by CURL anyways).

Comment: If you've got a lot to reset, then yeah - it'd probably be much easier to just create a new curl. But if it's just a couple, make the changes you need and curl'll handle/ignore the rest for you.

Comment: Small correction, that should be CURLOPT_HTTPGET instead of CURLOPT_GET.

Answer (score 3):

In PHP 5.5 you can use [curl_reset()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-reset.php)