# Fatal error curl_reset() undefined why?

Tags: php, curl

I am using curl to request another site for getting data. My code having `curl_reset()` funciton is working well at localhost, but when i have updated my code to server. Its giving error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_reset() in
>   /data/html/reviewkiller1.0/controller/searchController.php on line
>   2054

**Note:** I have checked for curl extension it is enabled.

Why it is so???

Comment: Please share your code..

Comment: Is curl module installed in the server?

Comment: @Jenz It probably does not matter which code OP uses. [`curl_reset()`](http://php.net/curl-reset) is an extension function. It might be a configuration or version issue.

Comment: @FMQB: in that case, init would fail first.

Comment: @HAL9000 exactly i am using simple curl request which is working but if i uses `curl_reset()` it stop working.

Comment: @Manwal What [`php_info()`](http://php.net/php-info) or [`phpversion()`](http://php.net/phpversion) says ? Version ?

Comment: @HAL9000 let me check

Comment: this answer would useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7392173/how-do-i-reset-curl-variables-in-php

Comment: @HAL9000 PHP Version 5.3.3

Comment: @Manwal see Karoly's Horvath answer. It is a version issue. Use link provided by Girish. It might be useful.

Answer (score 24):

Requires no PHP version updating.

```
if (!function_exists('curl_reset'))
{
    function curl_reset(&$ch)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
    }
}
```

Comment: nice little hack

Answer (score 21):

PHP is old on your server.

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-reset.php): `(PHP 5 >= 5.5.0)`

Comment: +1 for quick analyzing issue. I have not accepted it because answer not have solution

Comment: my PHP version is 5.6.19 and still got this error !

Answer (score 13):

My PHP version is 5.3 so i was not able to use `curl_reset()` function.

### Solution

I was using `curl_reset()` function for getting response of multiple curl request.
So i have removed `curl_reset()` and used

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, false);
```

Problem was after post request my get request was not giving response when i have set curl_post to false to my request it works well.

Conclusion: Its important keep calling setopt to switch between GET and POST request when you are using multiple curl request.

Comment: Thanks for this, helped a lot for a temporary solution until we upgrade our sever to PHP 7.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the solution tested 100% working:

Error from php-error-log due to using curl_reset with php version 5.4:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\Handler\curl_reset() in ...
```

Upgrade to php version 5.5 successfully resolved issue. If you are on cpanel upgrading php version takes only 3 or 4 clicks.

enjoy!

Please mark as answered if it resolve the issue. Thanks!

Comment: this solution is not work for me, I already upgrade my php version to 5.6.19

Comment: Thanks Dung work for me like charm. Thank you so much.