# Google API client authorization: Internal Server Error 500

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, authorization, google-oauth, internal-server-error

I'm using an OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications example code on remote web server.

```
$client->authenticate(...) causes
```

> Internal Server Error 500.

No idea why, can you help me please?

Here is the web address: http://imperiousgroup.com/gdrive/

And here is the code:

```
//index.php
require_once(__DIR__ ."/api/vendor/autoload.php");    
session_start();    
$client = new Google_Client();    
$client->setAuthConfig('client_secrets.json');    
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);    
if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {    
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);    
    $drive_service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);    
    $files_list = $drive_service->files->listFiles(array())->getItems();    
    echo json_encode($files_list);    
} else {    
    $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/gdrive/oauth2callback.php';    
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));    
}    

//oauth2callback.php    
require_once __DIR__ .'/api/vendor/autoload.php';    
session_start();    
$client = new Google_Client();    
$client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secrets.json');    
$client->setRedirectUri('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/gdrive/oauth2callback.php');    
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);    
if (!isset($_GET['code'])) {    
    $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();    
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($auth_url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));    
} else {    
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);    
}
```

Comment: Please format the code, for better readability, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Which PHP version are you using? 
I had a similar issue as I was using PHP 5.3 while the google api technically requires 5.4+.

If updating it is not an option, I was able to fix my specific issue by using the solution described here:
[SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25523004/fatal-error-curl-reset-undefined-why)

The call to `curl_reset()` is found in `/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php` in the google api client folder.