# Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\curl_reset() with php 7

Tags: php, guzzle

I am running steam api example code (taken from https://github.com/zyberspace/php-steam-web-api-client) and getting an error, saying

`Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\\Handler\\curl_reset()`

i looked it up, and the answer was: update php. My php is already php7. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');
$client = new \Zyberspace\SteamWebApi\Client('someverylongnumber');
$steamUser = new \Zyberspace\SteamWebApi\Interfaces\ISteamUser($client);
$response = $steamUser->GetPlayerSummariesV2('76561198059720690');
```

Comment: Can you share the code as well

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of guzzle being imported?

Comment: There is guzzlehttp in vendor folder. not sure how to check for multiple

Comment: Have you used the composer ?

Comment: I have tested and it is working great, i have PHP v5.5.9. I think you have not imported the dependencies properly.

Comment: I've run composer require --update-no-dev zyberspace/steam-web-api-client
 in the project folder. Now I have vendor folder, with the php files in it. I am getting no error on line $client = new \Zyberspace\SteamWebApi\Client('someverylongnumber');
 and $steamUser = new \Zyberspace\SteamWebApi\Interfaces\ISteamUser($client);
. Just the third line appears to be a problem. Given the facts that the first 2 lines are wokring, I deduced that the composer did it's thing correctly

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. It worked perfectly fine on my local installation and on the test server, but not on the other hosting company's installation.

On all three PHP 5.6 was installed, so it had definitely nothing to do with the PHP version.

I found this solution: removed curl_reset() and used

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, false);
```

As described in this question [Fatal error curl_reset() undefined why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25523004/fatal-error-curl-reset-undefined-why)

Unfortunately I didn't have enough 'reputations' here, so I couldn't simply up-vote that solution there.