# Google Adwords API Refresh Token Error

Tags: php, curl, google-ads-api

When trying to generate a refresh token for the Adwords APi I get the following error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\Handler\curl_reset() in /var/www/vhosts/instalmentlending.com/httpdocs/wp-content/plugins/sfprepo/inc/requests/adwords/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php on line 78
```

This is not something I would have expected to see. I'm guessing its a Curl issue but I user curl on the server already so I know it work's.

Any ideas community?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed this by forcing php in SSH to run at 7.

It turns out that via SSH my php version was dropped to the vendor prefixed 5.4.

For my server `/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php` is what worked.

If you are not using plesk just check the docs to find your php version locations.

Answer (score 0):

According to this post it is a PHP version issue:
[Fatal error curl_reset() undefined why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25523004/fatal-error-curl-reset-undefined-why)

They suggest upgrading PHP on the server or remove the curl_reset calls.

Comment: Im on php 7 though that person was on 3 and upgraded to 5.5